# Preventing user from tabbing outside of Frame

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my WPF application, I have a page which contains various buttons and a frame. Inside this frame is a number of textboxes.

On start, I set the focus to the first textbox inside my frame. Is there any way I can ensure that <kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles just the elements within the frame, and doesn't jump outside to the parent page?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I set

```
KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"
```

on the Frame.

Answer (score 0):

set `IsTabStop=false` for controls outside the frame

Comment: Thanks for your input. This didn't work in my case, but you pointed me in the right direction to finding [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532497/preventing-user-from-tabbing-outside-of-frame/6539612#6539612).

Answer (score -1):

`tabstop` will work.

now my alternative solution - just assumption: first element inside ur frame has tabindex equal to 5, last element inside frame has tabindex equal to 9. take the element that has maximum tabindex within the frame scope (i.e. according to assumption element with tabindex 9). on `PreviewKeyDown` event write the following code:

```
private void frames_max_tabindex_element_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyValue == 9 )
            element_that_has_tabindex_equal_to_frames_min_tab_index_minus_1.Focus();
        }
```

brief expl. (using assumtions to demonstrate idea) when focus is on the element of frame with tabindex 9, key down on **tab** will fire the `PreviewKeyDown` event. inside the method u are setting focus to the element that has tabindex equal to 4. and after **tab** key is released windows will set focus to the next tabindex i.e. to the element with tabindex equal to 5. so from tabindex = 9 u are jumping to the element with tabindex = 5

Comment: Don't do that. Modifying focus in between message handling will for sure mess up things in certain setups.

Comment: @Florian Greinacher what kind of setups do you mean? and why "for sure"?