# are there any known issues associated with modifying focus in between message handling

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio

Based on the comment i received on posted answer ([link's here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532497/preventing-user-from-tabbing-outside-of-frame/6533094#6533094)) I have a question. what problems may occur if I'm forcing to set focus on a certain winform elements?

i.e. whats wrong with this method (looping focus within container/panel/frame... components):

```
private void containers_max_tabindex_element_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyValue == 9 )
            element_that_has_tabindex_equal_to_containers_min_tab_index_minus_1.Focus();
        }
```

I'm already using that method for months and so far so good, no complaints from end-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's nonsense of course, Winforms already does that by default when you press the Tab key.  You won't win any prizes for the code snippet, it fails when you set the focus to a control that's disabled.  The much better way is to override ProcessCmdKey() to recognize Keys.Tab.  Return true so that Winforms doesn't try to tab to the next control.

Comment: tested myself, setting focus to a disabled control doesn't fail. all that happened - focus remained where it was before. And overriding ProcessCmdKey() and returning true on tab key press does exactly the same focus remains where it is.

Comment: Well, sure it fails.  It tabs to the wrong control.  Was that really your question?

Comment: it only fails for sure when setting focus to a disabled control. and I think scenario like that is pretty much avoidable. but as there's a chance of fail, i think ur answer counts as accepted. so before i accept, are there any issues, other than setting focus to disabled control, that might cause problems?